# Making a RESTful WPS using ZOO Project

Tags: rest, wps, ogc, zoo-project

I am trying to make a RESTful WPS using ZOO Project. According to the following OGC Papers [WPS 2.0 Interface Standard](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/14-065/14-065.html) and [Web Processing Service](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=24151) for WPS 2.0 and 1.0 respectively, it does seem possible to make a RESTful WPS. There is also [WPS 2.0 REST API TAMIS](https://52north.github.io/tamis-rest-api/) which seems to be a RESTful implementation of WPS.

Is there a way to make a RESTful WPS using ZOO Project? (I did not find anything about this mentioned in their documentation)

Comment: Whilst the TAMIS API you reference calls itself RESTful. It seems to rely on application/json. REST requires hypermedia. application/json is not hypermedia, so that API cannot be RESTful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make a conforming OGC WPS answer REST requests. The standard only allows for GET with KVP requests and POST of XML documents.

However looking at the TAMIS document you link to you might be able to make use of their "Generic WPS REST Proxy" to convert RESTful interactions to standards based WPS requests.  But it is likely to need a specific wrapper (as 52N use) to make it specific for the processes you want to access.

However for a general WPS provider like Zoo (or GeoServer) which can provide access to hundreds of processes and include subprocess calls in the request it is hard to see what REST gains you.

Comment: Not sure there's any such thing as a REST request.  REST is driven by hypermedia, you get a hypermedia document, the client understand the hypermedia and moves to the next resource by following a link.  The actual protocol used for the resource is not important, nor for HTTP the method.

Comment: This may be (happily) changing within the [OGC Feature API](https://www.ogc.org/standards/ogcapi-features) which relies on the [OpenAPI](https://www.openapis.org/): https://github.com/opengeospatial/ogcapi-features